# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/utils/NamespacePrefixList on creating the web service in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to create a web service using axis2.
I have created it.

I am following the below steps for getting the wsdl info.

```
Right click Project -> Run on server -> Next.
```

**No class found error is coming. Is any jar file is required.**

Please guide me how to resolve this.

> Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/utils/NamespaceMap at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:437) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:109) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:232) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:154) at

Answer (score 0):

You can download and include the XmlSchema jar in the `lib` folder of your dynamic web project `/WebContent/WEB_INF` folder.

But, this will only solve the problem temporarily. On creating WS client the XMLSchema jar will not get included. So check the compatibility of the version of your server with axis2 version (like Tomcat 6 created problem with axis2 1.7 but works fine with axis2 1.5.2).

On successful compatibility the XMLSchema jar will get included in the respective folder automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can correct your issue by referencing the XmlSchema jar in the lib folder. You can find the latest version of the jar file in the link below.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/DownloadXmlSchema142jar.htm

Comment: please provide a description as it should help others even if the link is revoked in future.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18005824)

Comment: @mmgross This is not a link only answer, the link is where to download a jar file, the inclusion of which fixed the issue.